# Dirac spinor and Lorentz vector

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-equation, spinors

Can we say that, just like any tensor has a transformation rule as per the definition, the Lorentz vector and spinor obey different transformation rules, which manifests as +1 /-1 upon 2π rotation? Is this the reason we use a different index for both of the above-mentioned objects? Why does the Dirac equation have 2-component spinors instead of 4-component spinors?

Comment: Is this question helpful to you?https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95457/

Comment: Above mentioned post is related but doesn't answer my doubt . @DanielC

Comment: "Dirac equation have 2-component spinors instead of 4-component spinors" - excuse me? On the contrary, Lorentz spinors have two components, and Dirac spinor has four.